# How can I remove space on bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created 3 div tags according to the grid rules

```
<div class="row">
    <div  class="col-md-3" style=" border:1px solid;"><uc1:ucretsizilan runat="server" ID="ucretsizilan" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style="   border:1px solid red;"><uc1:seriVitrin runat="server" ID="seriVitrin" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="   border:1px solid blue;"><uc1:nobetciBox runat="server" ID="nobetciBox" /></div>
</div>
```

[image: Print Image]

1. Div = Black
2. Div = Red
3. Div = Blue

Ranking musn't change and i would like to remove space between black and blue.
How can I remove it, So that black and blue divs should stand one under the other ?

Comment: Bootstrap grid comprises of 12 columns. You have 15 columns so they will not float left to right as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="left"> 
   <div  class="col-md-3" style=" border:1px solid;"><uc1:ucretsizilan runat="server" ID="ucretsizilan" /></div>
   <div class="col-md-3" style="   border:1px solid blue;"><uc1:nobetciBox runat="server" ID="nobetciBox" /></div>
</div>

<div class = "right> <div class="col-md-9" style="   border:1px solid red;"><uc1:seriVitrin runat="server" ID="seriVitrin" /></div> </div>
```

Comment: You can also position the blue div using position relative and absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You can acomplish this behavior with only 2 columns: left column (col-xs-3) and right column (col-xs-9).

Then you create 2 additional `div` elements in the left column, one for each element. Since the div is a block element, you will end up with one div bellow the other.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div style=" border:1px solid black;">
      black
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid blue;">
      blue
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9" style="border:1px solid red;">
    red
  </div>
</div>
```

Since you don't want to change the order of the elements, you could try something like the snippet bellow.

However i would recommend you reading more about the [`grid system`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). You're supposed to have a maximum of 12 columns in every row.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3" style="border: 1px solid #000">
    black
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9 pull-right" style="border: 1px solid #f00">
    <div>red</div>
    <div>red</div>
    <div>red</div>
    <div>red</div>
    <div>red</div>
    <div>red</div>
    <div>red</div>
    <div>red</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" style="border: 1px solid #00f">
    blue
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it working but color ranking was changed according to this code.
it was black blue red. would you write without change color ranking?

Comment: what is exactly this "color ranking"? you mean the order the divs appear in the html?

Comment: I've created 3 div tags and i named them in the order of writing because this order important for view on mobile. it musn't change. sorry my english is bad. @Romulo

Comment: Check if the second snippet suits your needs

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this, this will remove space in bootstrap grid.

Example

HTML

```
<div class="no-pad>
<div class="col-lg-12>
/*--Content--*/
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.no-pad [class*="col-"] {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: you should correct with attribute closure, it's a good method.

Answer (score 0):

According with the grid that provided bootstrap-grid you have to made some modifications like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div  class="col-md-3" style=" border:1px solid;">
        <uc1:ucretsizilan runat="server" ID="ucretsizilan" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="   border:1px solid blue;"><uc1:nobetciBox runat="server" ID="nobetciBox" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style="   border:1px solid red;"><uc1:seriVitrin runat="server" ID="seriVitrin" /></div>
</div>
```